# Как установить в .NetCore проект, (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer)

Tags: c#

Как установить в .NetCore проект,  (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer) через NuGet. Всё ставиться а, после запуска `dotnet run` выдаёт ошибку `Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.`  но проект работает.

```
dotnet --info
Программы командной строки .NET (2.1.104)

Product Information:
 Version:            2.1.104
 Commit SHA-1 hash:  48ec687460

Runtime Environment:
 OS Name:     Windows
 OS Version:  10.0.15063
 OS Platform: Windows
 RID:         win10-x64
 Base Path:   C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.1.104\

Microsoft .NET Core Shared Framework Host

  Version  : 2.0.6
  Build    : 74b1c703813c8910df5b96f304b0f2b78cdf194d
```

Пробовал ставить `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis` ставиться норм. Но `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` так же не ставиться.